# Google Play Console complains about title and short description

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-console

I received an email from Google complaining about this:
[image]

I have to say that I didn't add any new content/assets to my app since a while, I just made some fixes and improvements and now I'm getting this. Not sure what is this issue about.
The took like half a month to review this versions.

They also mentioned this:

> About the News policy Apps that select the ‘News’ category but exhibit
> content that does not meet these requirements are not permitted in the
> News category of the Play Store. News apps that require a user to
> purchase a membership must provide a content preview for users prior
> to purchase.

My app category is finance by the way:
[image]

Comment: Do you publish news updates on your app?

Comment: check for the category you have selected for your app, as it states you might have selected news, if thats not the case just mail them they will tell you what you should do

Comment: Ignoring or clicking through questionnaires without paying attention what is being asked can result in stuff like this happening, or far worse ;).  https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10177647?hl=en , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vjaFyDZVenc

Comment: I have told them already. My app has been always in the Finance category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue could be happening because in the "App Content" section, when getting a Content Rating, you could have selected the "News" category.

This is the category selection in the "App Content" > "Content ratings" Section:

[image: This is the category selection in the "App Content" Section]

You can find it here:
[image]

Also there is another option - "News Apps" - in the "App Content" section which looks like this:

[image]

Please check what option you have selected here, as I believe this is where the issue is.

Comment: It was on Finance category all the time and this has never been changed. I uploaded doces of updates of this app already. I'm starting to think that this is something more related to the new Google Play Console update

Comment: Updated question with info

Comment: Sorry, but you are talking about a different category (Store Category) than I am. I am talking about the "Content ratings" Category in "App Content". Can you add a screenshot of what option you chose in this selection? I have added a screenshot to my answer of what this section looks like.

Comment: Please check if in the "App Content" section you have not accidently selected "Yes" in the "News Apps" section.

Comment: Ah, didn't check that. I had selected News there, yes.

Comment: I've got a question related to this: my app manages different rents and as I mentioned it's on Finance category. I had plans to display in the future some news related to properties, laws, etc. Having Finance as main category a this News options selected should be correct?

Comment: We've found the problem! Thanks for the upvote and accepted answer :)

Comment: Yes, when you add the news section, you will have to select yes on that option. But after you select that, you will have to make sure you follow the policies here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9949730